# Computing pairwise differences in an R dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I create a simple dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
        UserId = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
        Answer_Date = as.Date(c("2010-12-31", "2011-12-29", "2012-12-25", "2013-12-10", "2014-12-31", "2010-10-31", "2011-10-28", "2013-10-31", "2015-10-31")),
        Q1 = c(3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4),
        Q2 = c(2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 8, 2, 6, 5),
      ) %>%
        group_by(UserId) %>%
        mutate(First_Date = min(Answer_Date)) %>%
        mutate(Last_Date  = max(Answer_Date)) %>%
        ungroup()
```

which gives me

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 x 6
  UserId Answer_Date    Q1    Q2 First_Date Last_Date 
  <chr>  <date>      <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1 A      2010-12-31      3     2 2010-12-31 2014-12-31
2 A      2011-12-29      1     0 2010-12-31 2014-12-31
3 A      2012-12-25      1     1 2010-12-31 2014-12-31
4 A      2013-12-10      0     2 2010-12-31 2014-12-31
5 A      2014-12-31      1     1 2010-12-31 2014-12-31
6 B      2010-10-31      4     8 2010-10-31 2015-10-31
7 B      2011-10-28      2     2 2010-10-31 2015-10-31
8 B      2013-10-31      5     6 2010-10-31 2015-10-31
9 B      2015-10-31      4     5 2010-10-31 2015-10-31
```

I now wish to compute the change in each subject's answers between the first and last date on which they answer the questionnaire. I start by writing

```
df_tmp <- df %>%
            filter(Answer_Date == First_Date) %>%
            select(c("UserId", "Q1", "Q2"))
colnames(df_tmp) <- c("UserId", paste0("First_Response_", c("Q1", "Q2")))
df <- merge(df, df_tmp, by = "UserId") 

df_tmp <- df %>%
            filter(Answer_Date == Last_Date) %>%
            select(c("UserId", "Q1", "Q2"))
colnames(df_tmp) <- c("UserId", paste0("Last_Response_", c("Q1", "Q2")))
df <- merge(df, df_tmp, by = "UserId")
```

giving me

```
> df
  UserId Answer_Date Q1 Q2 First_Date  Last_Date First_Q1 First_Q2 Last_Q1 Last_Q2
1      A  2010-12-31  3  2 2010-12-31 2014-12-31        3        2       1       1
2      A  2011-12-29  1  0 2010-12-31 2014-12-31        3        2       1       1
3      A  2012-12-25  1  1 2010-12-31 2014-12-31        3        2       1       1
4      A  2013-12-10  0  2 2010-12-31 2014-12-31        3        2       1       1
5      A  2014-12-31  1  1 2010-12-31 2014-12-31        3        2       1       1
6      B  2010-10-31  4  8 2010-10-31 2015-10-31        4        8       4       5
7      B  2011-10-28  2  2 2010-10-31 2015-10-31        4        8       4       5
8      B  2013-10-31  5  6 2010-10-31 2015-10-31        4        8       4       5
9      B  2015-10-31  4  5 2010-10-31 2015-10-31        4        8       4       5
```

I now wish to create two now columns, `Delta_Q1 = Last_Q1 - First_Q1` and `Delta_Q2 = Last_Q2 - First_Q2`, but (possibly) using `mutate, paste0("First_", c("Q1", "Q2")), paste0("Last_", c("Q1", "Q2"))` and `paste0("Delta_", c("Q1", "Q2"))`.

What is the correct syntax for computing the differences (or in general, some function of two variables) between pairs of columns sequentially? The reason I don't want to write the differences down manually is simple - the real dataframe has lots of pairs of columns.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two vector of columns and directly subtract them to create new columns.

```
first_r_col <- grep('First_Response', colnames(df))
last_r_col <- grep('Last_Response', colnames(df))
df[paste0('delta', seq_along(first_r_col))] <- df[last_r_col] - df[first_r_col]
```

Using `dplyr` `select` statement might be easy way to select the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df[paste0('delta', seq_along(first_r_col))]  <- 
         df %>% select(starts_with('Last_Response')) - 
         df %>% select(starts_with('First_Response'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach that does not require you creating the `First_Date` and `Last_Date` columns:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(UserId) %>%
  arrange(UserId, Answer_Date) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n()) %>%
  summarize(Delta_Q1 = diff(Q1),
            Delta_Q2 = diff(Q2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think much of that coding is needed, below is a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(UserId) %>% 
  arrange(Answer_Date) %>% 
  summarize(First_Q1 = first(Q1), 
            First_Q2 = first(Q2), 
            Last_Q1 = last(Q1),
            Last_Q2 = last(Q2)) %>% 
  mutate(Delta_Q1 = Last_Q1 - First_Q1,
         Delta_Q2 = Last_Q2 - First_Q2)
```

Gives the output of:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  UserId First_Q1 First_Q2 Last_Q1 Last_Q2 Delta_Q1 Delta_Q2
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A             3        2       1       1       -2       -1
2 B             4        8       4       5        0       -3
```

Comment: I deliberately did not want to use summarize, as I want to add columns to the entire data frame: I need to compute both time-series and cross-sectional properties of the answers as well as of the differences. I suppose I could summarize and then merge the two dataframes, but I prefer Ronaks' solution  as it allows me to use a prefix (FIRST_RESPONSE_PREFIX, LAST_RESPONSE_PREFIX) that I can change to identify the column names, making everything cleaner.  I have over 20 questions, so this is of practical importance.

Comment: I mean you could just `full_join()` afterwards to re-establish the full data frame with the full amount of rows and specify the suffix/prefix in the `full_join(.., suffix = c(..))` argument.

Answer (score 0):

With the benefit of hindsight, I missed the blindingly obvious answer, and made it harder than it should have been:

```
QUESTIONS <- c("Q1", "Q2")
FIRST_RESPONSE_PREFIX <- "First_"
LAST_RESPONSE_PREFIX  <- "Last_"
DELTA_RESPONSE_PREFIX <- "Delta_"

first_response_cols <- paste0(FIRST_RESPONSE_PREFIX, QUESTIONS)
last_response_cols  <- paste0(LAST_RESPONSE_PREFIX,  QUESTIONS)
delta_response_cols <- paste0(DELTA_RESPONSE_PREFIX, QUESTIONS)

df_tmp1 <- df %>%
              filter(Answer_Date == First_Answer_Date) %>%
              select(c("UserId", QUESTIONS))
colnames(df_tmp1) <- c("UserId", first_response_cols)
df   <- merge(df, df_tmp1, by = "UserId")

df_tmp2 <- df %>%
              filter(Answer_Date == Last_Answer_Date) %>%
              select(c("UserId", QUESTIONS))
colnames(df_tmp2) <- c("UserId", last_response_cols)
df  <- merge(df, df_tmp2, by = "UserId") 

df[delta_response_cols] <- df[last_response_cols] - df[first_response_cols]
```

When I run the code, I get exactly what i want:

```
> df
  UserId Answer_Date Q1 Q2 First_Answer_Date Last_Answer_Date First_Q1 First_Q2 Last_Q1 Last_Q2 Delta_Q1 Delta_Q2
1      A  2010-12-31  3  2        2010-12-31       2014-12-31        3        2       1       1       -2       -1
2      A  2011-12-29  1  0        2010-12-31       2014-12-31        3        2       1       1       -2       -1
3      A  2012-12-25  1  1        2010-12-31       2014-12-31        3        2       1       1       -2       -1
4      A  2013-12-10  0  2        2010-12-31       2014-12-31        3        2       1       1       -2       -1
5      A  2014-12-31  1  1        2010-12-31       2014-12-31        3        2       1       1       -2       -1
6      B  2010-10-31  4  8        2010-10-31       2015-10-31        4        8       4       5        0       -3
7      B  2011-10-28  2  2        2010-10-31       2015-10-31        4        8       4       5        0       -3
8      B  2013-10-31  5  6        2010-10-31       2015-10-31        4        8       4       5        0       -3
9      B  2015-10-31  4  5        2010-10-31       2015-10-31        4        8       4       5        0       -3
```

That said, thanks for the help - I learned something by looking at the suggested answers.